# Implementing a priority queue that can be iterated over in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I need to implement a priority queue for a project, but the STL's `priority_queue` is not indicated since we need to iterate over all elements and remove them randomly.

We are thinking about using the STL's `set` for this, wrapping it in a class to make it an ADT.

Is there a smarter solution for this?

How can we make it so some of `set`'s public member functions can be used publicly? We're interested in iterators, etc.

Apparently deriving the STL is unwise because of the lack of virtual destructors :/

---

New code:

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUE_H_
#define PRIORITYQUEUE_H_

#include <set>

template<typename T, template<typename X> class impl_type = std::set>
class PriorityQueue {
    typedef impl_type<T> set_type;
    typedef typename set_type::iterator iterator;
public:
    void push(const T& x) {
        insert(x);

    }

    void pop() {
        erase(begin());
    }

    const T& top() const {
        return *begin();
    }
};

#endif /* PRIORITYQUEUE_H_ */
```

So, we currently have this. The compiler doesn't complain about insert, but it does complain about `erase(begin())` and `return *begin()`:

`there are no arguments to 'begin' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'begin' must be available`

Why is this?

Comment: You should tag the thread as a homework.

Comment: This is a small part of a much larger project. But sure, I don't need code answers.

Comment: ADT? Algebraic Data Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to implement your own priority queue using `std::vector`, `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, and `std::pop_heap`. Isn't this how `std::priority_queue` is implemented? You'll just need to call `std::make_heap` again to fix the data structure when you remove a random element.

Do you need to iterate over the elements in order? There's a `std::sort_heap` algorithm to order the underlying `std::vector`.

Comment: make_heap and std::priority_queue may or may not be the right choice since they do not guarantee stability(note: sort order stability not crash stability.)

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need a priority queue ?

You need iterate over all items and remove randomly -> linked list

If you need to keep the list sorted, sort it at the beginning and then, when inserting new item, use insertion sort (insert new item on right place).

Answer (score 2):

STL's set should be usable to make what you want, although I must note that the list of requirements looks a little strange. You could just define a new type.

```
template<typename T, template<typename X> class impl_type = std::set> class prio_queue {
    typedef impl_type<T> set_type;
    typedef typename set_type::iterator iterator;
    // etc
public:
    // Forward the set's members
    T& top() {
        return *begin();
    }
    // etc
};
```

Comment: Please check the updated question, some errors returned with that.

Comment: @Francisco: That's because you didn't forward the set's members, like I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Then I do not understand the concept of forwarding.

Comment: @Francisco: You implement all the member functions of set in prio_queue that just forward to the set's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the example set by some of the other container adapters in the standard library use composition and make the type of the underlying container a template parameter.  Though since it is a school project that might be too much flexibility.  You might start by using composition with one of the existing Containers and build from there if necessary.